# RavenDB: Correct use of multi-map

Tags: nosql, ravendb

I have some documents that represent `Jobs`:

```
{
    "name": "Job 1",
    "startAt": "2013-12-13",
    "endAt": "2013-12-15"
},
{
    "name": "Job 2",
    "startAt": "2013-12-14",
    "endAt": "2013-12-16"
}
```

Based on these I want to display a timeline of events for a given date range. Rather than querying by each field and stitching the results together on the client, I was planning to create an index to return something like this:

```
{"Results":[
    {
        "name": "Job 1",
        "timestamp": "2013-12-13",
        "event": "started"
    },
    {
        "name": "Job 2",
        "timestamp": "2013-12-14",
        "event": "started"
    },
    {
        "name": "Job 1",
        "timestamp": "2013-12-15",
        "event": "ended"
    },
    {
        "name": "Job 2",
        "timestamp": "2013-12-16",
        "event": "ended"
    }
]}
```

They'll be some other 'events' for a job over time, recording when a payment is due etc that will also appear on the timeline - but hopefully there are enough details here to explain what I'm trying to do.

So far I've got this working with a multi-map index but from what I understand, multi-map is for indexing different document types whereas I have just the one.

```
public class Jobs_Timeline : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<Jobs_Timeline.IndexResult>
{
    public Jobs_Timeline()
    {
        AddMap<Job>(jobs => jobs.Select(x => new { x.Name, Timestamp = x.StartAt, Event = "started" }));
        AddMap<Job>(jobs => jobs.Select(x => new { x.Name, Timestamp = x.EndAt, Event = "ended" }));

        Store(x => x.Name, FieldStorage.Yes);           
        Store(x => x.Timestamp, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.Event, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }

    public class IndexResult
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Event { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I want to know is:

- Based on the results I want, should I be using an index for this (or a results transformer, denormalised docs etc)
- If I should be using an index, should I be using a multi-map over just one document type?

New to both Raven and NoSQL so I may be going about this completely the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfectly acceptable approach and I have done something almost identical.

The only thing I would change is make the events more descriptive.

i.e

```
AddMap<Job>(jobs => from j in jobs
                    select new 
                    { 
                        x.Name, 
                        Timestamp = x.EndAt, 
                        Event = "ended",
                        EventType = "job"
                    });
```

Adding the event type, when you add multiple events in the future, will allow you to filter events by type.

i.e

Show me all Job Events

Show me all Register Events

etc.

Edit: Also its fine to index the same documents multiple times, you're breaking a single document into multiple events.

Comment: Cheers, it worked well enough just nice to know it's the right way. My event is actually an enum but good point about the type, helpful for querying later on.